# Dart: Reference a variable name from the variable itself

Tags: dart

I’m trying to get the variable name instead of the value to pass it to another method

eg.

```
String myString = "xyz";

String getVariableName(String s){
  // What i want is if the above string is passed [getVariableName(myString)] 
 //i want it to return ['myString']
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is generally not possible.  At best, if there are a finite number of `String` variables you care about, you could manually make a collection of them, and then search it:

```dart
final stringVariables = <String, String Function()>{
  'myString': () => myString,
  'myOtherString': () => myOtherString,
};

var myString = 'xyz';
var myOtherString = 'abc';

String getVariableName(String s) {
  for (var entry in stringVariables.entries) {
    if (entry.value() == s) {
      return entry.key;
    }
  }
  return '';
}

void main() {
  print(getVariableName('xyz')); // Prints: myString
  
  myString = 'foo';
  print(getVariableName('foo')); // Prints: myString
}
```

Note that `stringVariables`'s above must use a `Function` as a thunk to delay evaluation of the variable; otherwise the variable name would be associated with whatever value it happened to have when `stringVariables` is first accessed and wouldn't work if your variables are reassigned.

All that said, I don't really recommend doing any of this.  This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/).  You should be asking about whatever it is you ultimately want to do, and there probably is a better way to accomplish that task.